# TypeORM - Many-to-many relation, with conditions on the joined table

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I've a **many-to-many** relation between a `podcasts` table and an `episodes` table. A podcast can have multiple episodes, and an episode can be part of multiple podcasts.

```js
@Entity({ name: 'podcasts' })
export class Podcast extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToMany(() => Episode, (episode) => episode.podcasts, { nullable: true })
  @JoinTable({ name: 'podcast_episode_join' })
  episodes: Episode[];
}

@Entity({ name: 'podcast_episodes' })
export class Episode extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column('boolean', { default: false })
  is_published: boolean;

  @ManyToMany(() => Podcast, (podcast) => podcast.episodes, { nullable: true, lazy: true })
  podcasts: Podcast[];
}
```

I'm trying to fetch **one podcast** (from its specified id) with **all its episodes** that are **published** (`is_published = true`). My code below is working well.

**But:** in the case where my podcast has no episode, it returns nothing (`undefined`), instead of at least returning the `podcast` object (with an empty `episodes` property). What I'm doing wrong?

```js
const podcast = await this.podcastRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('podcast')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('podcast.episodes', 'episode')
  .where('podcast.id = :id', { id })
  .andWhere('episode.is_published = :isPub', { isPub: true })
  .getOne();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to get it. The results were filtered only when the condition is true: `is_published = true`. But when there is no episode in the podcast, `is_published` is `null`. So we need to check if this property is either `true` or `NULL`.

Also we have to be sure that the `is_published` column in the `episode` table can never be `NULL` when a new row is created. That it always has a default value (here in this case: `false`).

```js
const podcast = await this.podcastRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('podcast')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('podcast.episodes', 'episode')
  .where('podcast.id = :id', { id })

  .andWhere(
    new Brackets((qb) => {
      qb
        // if episode is published
        .where('episode.is_published = :isPub', { isPub: true })
        // if there is no episode
        .orWhere('episode.is_published IS NULL', { isPub: true });
    }),
  )

  .getOne();
```